# MySQL optimizing by splitting table into two

Tags: mysql

I currently have a table called `map_tiles` that will eventually have around a couple hundred thousand rows. Each row in this table represents an individual tile on a world map of my game. Currently, the table structure is like so:

```
id      int(11)    PRIMARY KEY
city_id int(11)
type    varchar(20)
x       int(11)    INDEX KEY
y       int(11)    INDEX KEY
level   int(11)
```

I also want to be able to store a stringified JSON object that will contain information regarding that specific tile. Since I could have 100,000+ rows, I want to optimize my queries and table design to get the best performance possible.

So here is my scenario: A player loads a position, say at 50,50 on the worldmap. We will load all tiles within a 25 tile radius of the player's coordinate. So, we will have to run a `WHERE` query on this table of hundreds of thousands of rows in my `map_tiles` table.

So, would adding another field of type `text`  called `data` to the existing table prove better performance? However, this would slow down the main query.

Or, would it be worth it to create a separate table called `map_tiles_data`, that just has the structure like so:

```
tile_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY
data    text
```

And I could run the main query that finds the tiles within the radius of the player from the `map_tiles`, and then do a `UNION ALL` possibly that just pulls the JSON stringified `data` from the second table?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I should have clarified. The second table if used, would not have a row for each corresponding tile in the `map_tiles` table. A row will only be added if data is to be stored on a map tile. So by default, there will be 0 rows in the `map_tiles_data` table, while there could be 100,000 thousand rows in the `map_tiles` table. When a player does x action, then the game will add a row to `map_tiles_data`.

Comment: Do you need all the data in your json object all the time when you request it? If you do I can't blame you for using it. If you do need only some information stored in the json object at a given time, it is a waste of space. Depending on what you use as programming language, you might be able to serialize your data instead of making it a string, saving you some storage capacity.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks for the response! Yes, nearly every query that pulls rows from the `map_tiles` database will utilize the JSON data except maybe one query that runs maybe 1% of the time the other main query is ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to store data in separate table. You can use the same table. But you have to use InnoDB plugin and set `innodb_file_format=barracuda` and as data is going to be text, use `ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic (or Compressed)`

InnoDB will store the text out side the ROW page, so having data in the same table is efficient than having it in separate table (you can avoid joins and foreign keys). Also add index on x and y as all your queries are based on the location

**Useful reading:**

Innodb Plugin in “Barracuda” format and ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC. In this format Innodb stores either whole blob on the row page or only 20 bytes BLOB pointer giving preference to smaller columns to be stored on the page, which is reasonable as you can store more of them. BLOBs can have prefix index but this no more requires column prefix to be stored on the page – you can build prefix indexes on blobs which are often stored outside the page.

COMPRESSED row format is similar to DYNAMIC when it comes to handling blobs and will use the same strategy storing BLOBs completely off page. It however will always compress blobs which do not fit to the row page, even if KEY_BLOCK_SIZE is not specified and compression for normal data and index pages is not enabled.

Don't think that I am referring only to BLOBs. From storage prospective BLOB, TEXT as well as long VARCHAR are handled same way by Innodb.

Ref: https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/

Comment: Sorry for the plate reply, but you speak of an InnoDB plugin. Is this not possible with the regular InnoDB that comes with MySQL 5.6?

Comment: No need to worry about plugin if you are using 5.6.

From MySQL 5.5, the InnoDB Plugin is also included, but it becomes the built-in version of InnoDB in MySQL Server, replacing the version previously included as the built-in InnoDB engine

Comment: Thank you for the information, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue of storing data in one table or two tables is not really your main issue.  The issue is getting the neighboring tiles.  I'll return to that in a moment.

JSON can be a convenient format for flexibly storing attribute/value pairs.  However, it is not so useful for accessing the data in the database.  You might want to consider a hybrid form.  This suggests another table, because you might want to occasionally add or remove columns

Another consideration is maintaining history. You may want history on the JSON component, but you don't need that for the rest of the data.  This suggests using a separate table.

As for optimizing the `WHERE`.  I think you have three choices.  The first is your current approach, which is not reasonable.

The second is to have a third table that contains all the neighbors within a given distance (one row per tile and per neighboring tile).  Unfortunately, this method doesn't allow you to easily vary the radius, which might be desirable.

The best solution is to use a GIS solution.  You can investigate MySQL's support for geographic data types [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-spatial-data.html).

Comment: Hi! First off, thanks for the reply. May I ask what do you mean by my current approach, I'm confused as to which bit your referencing. The third table would prove a problem, because as you mentioned, at anytime I can update the game to change the radius at which neighboring tiles are loaded. And as for GIS, is this necessary? I've just been simply loading tiles in a chunk by doing something similar to `WHERE (x >= ? AND y >= ?) AND (x <= ? AND y <= ?)`

Answer (score 0):

Where you store your JSON really won't matter much. The main performance problem you face is the fact that your `WHERE` clause will not be able to make use of any indexes (because you're ultimately doing a greater / less than query rather than a fixed query). A hundred thousand rows isn't that many, so performance from this naive solution might be acceptable for your use case; ideally you should use the geospatial types supported by MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated my post to include indexes. :)